# Preventing React-Leaflet from unnecessary re-render of Map component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-memo

Because my app handles the mobile and desktop views in two different components, I've needed to use [useContext API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) to distribute state/propa across them.

I have a Map component and upon moving from mobile to desktop and vice-versa the Map refreshes.

According to the React docs regarding React memo:

> If your component renders the same result given the same props, you
> can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some
> cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip
> rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

So at first my thinking was "Why don't I memoize the current `zoom` prop of the map?" Because when a different breakpoint is hit (going from mobile or Desktop and vv) it causes a re-render.

But then I read this right below the previous passage:

> React.memo only checks for prop changes. If your function component
> wrapped in React.memo has a useState or useContext Hook in its
> implementation, it will still rerender when state or context change.

However under that there is this!

> By default it will only shallowly compare complex objects in the props
> object. If you want control over the comparison, you can also provide
> a custom comparison function as the second argument.
>
> This method only exists as a **performance optimization.** Do not rely on
> it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

So I tried it anyway but first I used a map method to get the current zoom and then save it via [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) and [local-storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) thereby when one enters the mobile or desktop at least the user will get the last zoom entered on the map.

[image: from desktop to mobile]

As you can see there is a slight lag.

So this is my implementation:
The Map function:

```
function currentMapViewPropsAreEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return (
    prevProps.currentMapView === nextProps.currentMapView &&
    prevProps.Map === nextProps.Map &&
    prevProps.TileLayer === nextProps.TileLayer
  );
}

function MyMap({ currentMapView, Map, TileLayer }) {
  var [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false);
  var [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState(null);
    
  var handleWaypointsOnMapRef = useRef(handleWaypointsOnMap);

  var mapRef = useRef();
  var mapRefForRoutingMachine = useRef();
  var { state } = userState();
  var { dispatch } = userDispatch();
  var {
    currentMap,
    isRoutingVisible,
    removeRoutingMachine,
    isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo,
    markers
  } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    handleWaypointsOnMapRef.current = handleWaypointsOnMap;
  }); // update after each render
    
  function handleOnViewportChanged(e) {
    var { current = {} } = mapRef;
    var { leafletElement: map } = current;

    map.on('zoomend', function() {
      var zoom = map.getZoom();

      dispatch({
        type: 'setMapZoom',
        payload: {
          currentMapView: zoom
        }
      });
    });
  }

  function handleOnLocationFound(e) {
    var { current = {} } = mapRef;
    var { leafletElement: map } = current;
    map.setZoom(currentMapView);

    var latlng = e.latlng;
    var radius = e.accuracy;
    var circle = L.circle(latlng, radius);
    circle.addTo(map);
  }

  return (
    <Map
      preferCanvas={true}
      id="myMap"
      animate={animate}
      zoom={currentMapView}
      ref={mapRef}
      onViewportChanged={handleOnViewportChanged}
      onClick={e => handleWaypointsOnMap(e)}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url={`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/${process.env.MAPBOX_USERNAME}/${
          process.env.MAPBOX_STYLE_ID
        }/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=${process.env.MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}`}
        attribution='Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery &copy; <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>'
      />

      {mapRef && (
        <Routing
          isRoutingVisible={isRoutingVisible}
          ref={mapRefForRoutingMachine}
          markers={markers}
          stringify={stringify}
          isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo={isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo}
          removeRoutingMachine={removeRoutingMachine}
          userLocation={userLocation}
        />
      )}
    </Map>
  );
}

var MemoizedMyMap = React.memo(MyMap, currentMapViewPropsAreEqual);
```

And this the Dashboard, so you can see I'm passing the actual `Map` as a prop with the `zoom` property:

```
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

import { userState, userDispatch } from '../components/Context/UserContext.jsx';

const MyMap = dynamic(() => import('../components/Map/MyMap.jsx'), {
  ssr: false
});

var Dashboard = ({ props }) => {
  var { state } = userState();
  var { dispatch } = userDispatch();
  var { currentMapView } = state;
  return (
    <>

              <MyMap Map={Map} TileLayer={TileLayer} currentMapView={currentMapView} />
            
    </>
  );
};
```

So does anyone have any ideas how I can keep the map props/state intact while traversing the breakpoints between mobile and desktop.

Comment: You're using the `Map` component as opposed to `MapContainer`...are you using react-leaflet version 2?  Or just aliasing `MapContainer` to `Map`, but using RL version 3?

Comment: @SethLutske I am using `"react-leaflet": "^2.7.0",`

Comment: Are you able to switch to v3?  I know that when I was working a lot with v2, unnecessary rerenders were around every corner.  A lot of that has been very well addressed in v3.  Is that a possibility?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I guess I can give it a try!

Comment: I know it doesn't really answer your question, and will probably require alot of refactoring, but it may be worth a look. I'm running into unecessary rerendering issues with `useContext` in another projet (not lefalet related), and I'd love any method I can use to not worry about it!  I'll think on your conundrum when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks @SethLutske good luck mate!